# scanf makes first element null in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to get 2, length of 8, inputs. With the code I have, my problem is that bit1[0] is null. Where is my problem ?

[This is kind of debug I have, to see it null-ifies the first element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqxo4.png)

PS: Dont mind about the calculations I have at the bottom of the code. I am trying to create a calculator that does binary summation. I still couldn't try my code, it can be meaningless to do it in the way I do. But its not the question I am asking so please avoid giving advice on that one. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char bit1[8];
    char bit2[8];
    int result[8];
    int sum;
    int dig1;
    int dig2;
    printf("Enter first binary number without any whitespaces!\t");
    scanf("%s", bit1);

    printf("Enter second binary number without any whitespaces!\t");
    scanf(" %s", bit2);
    int handle = 0;
    puts(bit1);
    puts(bit2);
    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
        //printf("%d", bit1[i] - '0');
        dig1 = bit1[i] - '0';
        dig2 = bit2[i] - '0';
        if(dig1 + dig2 + handle < 2){
            result[i] = dig1 + dig2 + handle;
            handle = 0;
        } else {
            result[i] = (dig1 + dig2 + handle)%2;
            handle = 1;
        }
        printf("dig1: %d\tdig2: %d\thandle: %d\n", dig1, dig2, handle);
        printf("%d is added!\n", result[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%c", result[i]);
    }
    printf(" And carry is: %d", handle);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATED

Working code is:

```
    char bit1[9];
    char bit2[9];
    int result[8];
    int sum;
    int dig1;
    int dig2;
    printf("Enter first binary number without any whitespaces!\t");
    scanf("%8s", bit1);

    printf("Enter second binary number without any whitespaces!\t");
    scanf("%8s", bit2);
```

Rest are the same

Comment: you should use a length limiter to avoid buffer overflows -- i.e. `scanf("%7s", bit1);` here etc.  And always check the return value of scanf ot see if reading succeeded before you try and use the data read.

Comment: The `i` loop reads more data than was read (you only read 7 digits but try to process 8)

Comment: @M.M I am sorry if this not the way to reply to you. I am kinda new to the asking questions. However, on my code I dont have any limitations on the input. Therefore, there has to be 8 elements in bit1, shouldn't be ? Since I use exactly the same formatting for bit2 and has 8 elements.

Comment: @user3121023 that actually worked. So what I understand is that to have 8 bit input then I have to write "%9s" in which 9th element is the whatever enter button sends ? 
Also why result[8] is 8 in this case ?

Comment: No — you use `char bit1[9]` to allow for a null terminator, but in the conversion specifier, you use `"%8s"` because there's an 'off-by-one' error (or "different-by-one" distinction) between variable definitions and conversion specifiers.  The length in the conversion specifier is the number of characters permitted before the null; in the variable definition, the length is the number of characters, including the null byte.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you. But what I dont understand is why always result[8] becomes 8. Because I dont make any assignment to it. But no random value is assigned to it. Every run i get 8

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get a string (that is exactly 8 characters) from user input you should write:

```
char string[9];
scanf("%8s", string);
```

The reason you need `char string[9]` and not `char string[8]` is because a C-string always ends in the null-character (0 or '\0'). Thus, you need one extra space to store that null-character.

Don't forget to always use `%8s`. If the user input then exceeds the 8 characters you want, C will automatically *cut off* the exceeding characters.